# LXC: shared folder in guest machine doesn't work as expect

Tags: mount, symlink, lxc

Host machine has the following dirs:

- /srv/releases/A/db/DB1/
- /srv/releases/A/db/DB2/
- /srv/releases/A/files/
- /srv/releases/B/db/DB1/
- /srv/releases/B/db/DB2/
- /srv/releases/B/files/
- /srv/current - symlink to /srv/sources/releases/A/

In lxc config:

```
lxc.mount.entry=/srv/current/db/DB1 /var/lib/lxc/xxx/rootfs/srv/remote/db none bind,ro,create=dir 0 0
lxc.mount.entry=/srv/current/files /var/lib/lxc/xxx/rootfs/srv/remote/files none bind,ro,create=dir 0 0
```

In the guest machine i have access to /srv/remote/db & /srv/remote/files - everything ok. But if i change symlink on host machine to /srv/releases/B (ln -sfn /srv/releases/B /srv/current), on guest machine nothing happened, i still get contents of /srv/releases/A. Even if you rename the folder /srv/releases/A to /srv/releases/C, nothing is changed.

How is possible? Is there a way to replace the contents of a folder /srv/current atomically without restart container?

Thank you!